# Remove lines beginning with the same semi-colon delimited part with regex

Tags: regex

I would like to use *Notepad++* to remove lines with duplicate beginning of line. For example, I have a semi-colon separated file like below:

```
string at the beginning of line 1;second string line 1; final string line1;
string at the beginning of line 2;second string line 2; final string line2;
string at the beginning of line 1;second string line 3; final string line3;
string at the beginning of line 1;second string line 4; final string line4;
```

I would like to remove the third and fourth lines as they have the same first substring as the first line and get the following result:

```
string at the beginning of line 1;second string line 1; final string line1;
string at the beginning of line 2;second string line 2; final string line2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the following regex:

```
^(([^;]*;).*\R(?:.*\R)*?)\2.*
```

Or

```
^(([^;]*;).*\R(?:.*\R)*?)\2.*(?:$|\R)
```

And replace with `$1`.

The idea is to find and capture text in the beginning of a line that consists of non-semicolon characters up to `;` (`[^;]*;`), then match the rest of the line (with `.*\R`), then 0 or more lines (`(?:.*\R)*?`) up to a line that starts with the captured text in group 2, matching it to the end and capturing into the second group that we can use later.

The drawback is that you will have to click Replace All several times until no match is found.

Thanks go to @nhahtdh who noticed a bug with my previous `^(([^;]*).*\R(?:.*\R)*?)\2.*` regex that can overfire.

[image]

Comment: If the text contains only the first 2 lines in the example, applying your regex will cause one of those lines to be deleted, since you didn't force field delimiter to present in capturing group 2. Use `^(([^;]*;).*\R(?:.*\R)*?)\2.*(?:\R|$)` instead and click Replace All button repeatedly.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Thank you for a constructive criticism and help.